# Create content to pass to child with event handling in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a requirement where in I am making a reusable modal, for which the structure is as shown below:

```
--Parent.js
  --ModalComponent.js
```

In parent, I am creating the content for modal on a click,

```
getModalContent = () => {
   let ModalBody = (
     <div onClick={this.clickableHandler}> //I want this clickableHandler to trigger in child(modal component)
       This is clickable
     </div>
   );
   this.setState({modalContent: ModalBody});
}
render(){
   return(
      <button onClick={this.getModalContent}>Open modal</button>
      <ModalComponent modalContent={this.state.ModalContent}/>
   );
}
```

In child(Modal) component, on click of that div, I want the function clickableHandler to get triggered.
ModalComponent.js----

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ModalComponent extends Component{
   clickableHandler = () => {
      console.log('I am clicked');
   }
   render(){
       return (
          <div>
             {this.props.modalContent}
          </div>
       );
   }
}
```

But by doing so, I not getting the function clickableHandler() function to get triggered in modal, ie, the child component. Let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the clickableHandler in the parent not in the modal. You are registering the event callback in your parent and refer to it as this.clickableHandler. In this case 'this' refers to parent but there is no class method called clickable handler on the parent. I hope it helps.

Comment: I understand, but if I want an event that I want to be triggered inside child, how would I do that? I want to dynamically create content for child, eg: let childBody = (<button onClick={hitChildFunc()}>Click me</button>); and store it in store and pass this in child calling like: <chilldcomponent content={this.state.childBody}/>

Answer (score 0):

Since the `clickHandler` is actually defined inside `ModalComponent` and you are providing the content from the Parent component, its probably a good idea to make use of `renderProps` in `ModalComponent` like

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ModalComponent extends Component{
   clickableHandler = () => {
      console.log('I am clicked');
   }
   render(){
       return this.props.children(this.clickableHandler);
   }
}
```

and use it like

```
getModalContent = (clickableHandler) => {
   return (
     <div onClick={clickableHandler}> 
       This is clickable
     </div>
   );
}
render(){
   return(
      <button onClick={this.getModalContent}>Open modal</button>
      <ModalComponent>
          {getModalContent}
      </ModalComponent>

   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the clickHandler function in the parent component. To dynamically change the child components, you can update the Parent state, and pass this needed values down as props. Every time state/props update the component affected will re-render. Give this a go.

Parent Component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      modalContent: '',
      childComponent: ''
    }
    this.getModalContent = this.getModalContent.bind(this)
    this.clickableHandler = this.clickableHandler.bind(this)
  }

  getModalContent () {
    let ModalBody = (
      <div onClick={this.clickableHandler}>
      </div>
    )
    this.setState({modalContent: ModalBody})
  }
  clickableHandler () {
    this.setState({
      childComponent: yourData
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getModalContent}>Open Modal</button>
        <ModalComponent modalContent={this.state.modalContent}
          childComponent={this.state.childComponent} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Parent



class ModalComponent extends Component {
      render () {
        return (
          <div>
            {this.props.modalContent}
            <AnotherChild childBody={this.props.childComponent} />
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default ModalComponent
```